# I attempted to install cuda drivers, and now almost everything is broken

Tags: cuda

I tried to install CUDA tookit 5.0 on ubuntu 12.04 and the installation proceeded OK.

After rebooting however, all I get is a terminal login. I've attempted to start the display manager with `sudo start lightdm` and it says all OK, but just hangs the prompt when it finishes loading without ever starting any display manager. `sudo start gdm` just flickers and goes back to the prompt.

There is no network connection on the machine either. It usually connects to a wireless network with remembered credentials.

What can I do to recover the machine?

Comment: Uninstalling the cuda drivers didn't help? What packages did you install or what guide did you follow?

Comment: I attempted to uninstall the cuda drivers by deleting the /usr/local/cuda-5.0 directory as the installer said, but that caused the screen to go totally black on reboot. I took the machine downstairs to get a wired internet connection, sshed into the machine, installed http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-310.19-driver.html and now everything is working again. Sheesh, do not ever mess with CUDA.

Comment: Did you ever get CUDA working?

Comment: Yes, at a later point with a later version of the driver. I'm not sure how sorry.

Comment: @Nathan I also had problem installing CUDA from official packages: http://askubuntu.com/questions/404091/ Can you please confirm my bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1268211