# What do you do when Nvidia-CUDA drivers break Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, cuda

I wanted to try some CUDA programming, so natually I installed all the Nvidia-CUDA* packages. After reboot, I can log in, but then there is only a black screen, and the cursor.

Even after I remove the packages from ctrl+alt+F2 terminal and reboot, I can't see anything after logging in - even as guest account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver/163808#comment518796_163808) copied from the wiki worked to fix it.

The question is, why do Ubuntu's official CUDA packages break everything? [I filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1268211).